# AWS RDS PostgreSQL Upgrade from 9.6.22 to 10.17

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds, rds

I just finished upgrading my AWS RDS database engine from 9.6.22 to 10.17. I used these steps to make the upgrade using the AWS Console:

Create snapshot of target database to upgrade
Restore snapshot
Upgrade the restored snapshot's (which is now a new instance) DB Engine version.

After I did all of this, everything seems fine but when I access the database, this warning message appears

```
WARNING: psql major version 9.6, server major version 10.
     Some psql features might not work.
```

I want to know the meaning of this warning because I am fairly new in AWS as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Your psql client is using version 9.6, whereas the server it is connecting to was upgraded to major version 10. You can possibly get rid of the warning by upgrading your `psql` client.